# Send emails from ubuntu virtual machine and use catchmail: Could not execute: smtp://localhost:1025

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using ubuntu on my virtual machine. I would like to send emails using catchmail as described here: http://berk.es/2011/05/29/mailcatcher-for-drupal-and-other-php-applications-the-simple-version/

I am trying to send emails like that:

```
//Mailer class:
class Mailer extends PHPMailer
{
public $UTF8Encode = false;
public function __construct($param = null)
{   
    parent::__construct($param);
    $this->Mailer = 'sendmail';
    $this->Sendmail = 'smtp://localhost:1025';
    $this->From   = 'xxxx@xxxx.com';
    $this->FromName = 'Support';
    $this->WordWrap = 50;
    $this->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
}
}

....etc....
```

And:

```
//Sending emails

$mail = new Mailer();
$mail->Body = "xxxx";
$mail->Subject = "xxx";
$mail->From = 'xxxx@xxxx.org';
$mail->FromName = 'Support';
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->AddAddress(xxxx@xxxx.com);
```

And I am getting the error:

```
Could not execute: smtp://localhost:1025
```

Comment: you're telling PHPMailer to use sendmail (an command line program) but you are using a stmp server url as command? you should change the Mailer to `'smtp'` or something like that

Comment: i checked it in the source, it should be: `$this->Mailer = 'smtp';`

Comment: @Mogria, thank you very much. Now, I am getting the error: "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."

Comment: Are you sure you've specified the correct port for your local SMTP server? And you may need to authenticate to your server ...

Comment: Hm, I don't know. I am using the mailcatcher and according to their website: http://mailcatcher.me/ I have to use the smtp://127.0.0.1:1025

Comment: You need to seperate this stuff
`$mail->Host = "localhost";`
`$mail->Port = 1025;` i'm going to post an answer

Comment: Great, it works like that. Please post the answer and I will confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->Mailer = 'sendmail';
$this->Sendmail = 'smtp://localhost:1025';
```

The problem with this is you're telling PHPMailer to use a command line program called `sendmail` instead of using smtp. And PHPMailer tries to do something like:

```
exec("smtp://localhost:1025 --args-and-stuff");
```

And as you can tell this won't work.

To tell PHPMailer to use smtp you need to do the following:

```
$this->Mailer = 'smtp';
$this->Host = 'localhost';
$this->Port = 1025;
```

If your SMTP server needs Authentification you can do that as follows:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "yourname@yourdomain";
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
```